# Puppeteer evaluate not executing required function

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've got a little app i've written with node.js and puppeteer. I'm trying to require a function from a different file into my `evaluate` callback, however the function never fires and causes `evaluate` to fail. Here is a pretty simple example, and maybe somebody can see if i'm just doing something stupid here.

Evaluate is called from File A

`product = await page.evaluate( source.getProductInformation )`

`source.getProductInformation` is defined in File B, this function fails when I call a function I require from within File B

`const priceSavePercent = calculateSavePercentage(priceWasNum, priceCurrentNum)`

`calculateSavePercentage` is simply required at the top of File B `const { calculateSavePercentage } = require('../modules/helpers')`

I try to console log everywhere and don't get any output to my console, and my evaluate callback doesn't return the object it's suppose to. Is there a different way i'm suppose to require dependencies into File B? I have an npm package and a constant also required in File B and both don't cause issues. Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you evaluate, you are accessing the page you are scraping javascript, not your own so that function isn't defined you could try something like this.

```
await page.evaluate((source) => {
    source.getProductInformation(); 
}, source);
```

Comment: ahh i think i see what you are saying. Pass what i need through eval instead of trying to require it in a different file.

Comment: Exactly, you need to pass it as a parameter since you can't access variables or functions that are defined outiside the evaluate.